# Custom Post Type Posts Not Showing Up in Admin

Tags: custom-post-types

I am using this theme called IronBand.  It has a few custom post types, and one of them is called "Gig."

I created some custom posts under that Custom Post Type.  Later, I wanted to changed the name of the Custom Post Type to "Show," so I fiddled with some php files.  It seemed like it was too complicated to change everything accordingly, so I replaced the php files I fiddled with to the original php files.

Now in the admin panel of "Gig," it says "No Gigs Found" Even if above the post list it says there are 17 published posts.  How could I make the published posts show up again?

Comment: I am not sure this is answerable without knowing exactly what you "fiddled" with and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fiddled, it's possible that your custom posts were created with your "Shows" post type, not "Gig".

You could check that in the database directly using PHPMyAdmin or whichever tool your host offers.

In PHPMyAdmin look for your wp_posts (the wp_ could be different) and look at all of the posts probably clicking on the ID column to sort the newest to the top, then scroll to the right and look for the post_type column of a row that contains one of your test posts.

It's not ideal, but you can now delete those posts (you should also find the posts_meta for them), or change the post_type column. Or just leave them alone and they shouldn't cause you any trouble. Unless you create another post type called Shows which could bring them back.

Comment: Thanks, you lead me to the right direction. How I fixed it at the end was changing the dates of the posts in the DB to today's date. Not sure why exactly.